# Changing a CSS property of an element when that element scrolls past a line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a website, within this website, there is a `scroll` icon that has a `fixed` position and thus scrolls with the user. Because of the duotone design of the website, I'd like this icon to change color when it goes from a light to a dark background. Small example:
[image]

As you can see, the `scroll` text is now white, on a dark background. However, when it scrolls over to the white side, I'd like the `scroll` text to become dark.

What I did try to do is use the `waypoints` library to make every light section a waypoint and then change colors like this:

```
$('.light').waypoint(function(direction) {
    $(".scroll").find('span').css('color', '#000');
});
```

However, this would only activate when the user reaches the bottom of the `.light` element.

Is there a way to do this in a smoother fashion? Thanks.

---

*edit* Like asked in the comments, here's a codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZyYBKM

Comment: Can you provide a CodePen or JSFiddle with the relevent code please.

Comment: @JamesDouglas Added a codepen :-)

Comment: The current codepen doesn't change to black on the bottom of the light section.

Comment: @JiFus My mistake, forgot to include the waypoint library. It works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this is possible.
To achieve this effect you will have to set an offset.
In this case the offset would be 100%.

The updated code:

```
$('.light').waypoint({
  handler: function(direction) {
    if(direction == "down") {
     $(".scroll").find('div').css('background', '#252A2F');
     $(".scroll").find('span').css('color', '#252A2F');
    } else {
      // Scrolling up, reverse the process
     $(".scroll").find('div').css('background', '#ffffff');
     $(".scroll").find('span').css('color', '#ffffff');
    }
  },
  offset: '100%'
});
$('.dark').waypoint({
  handler: function(direction) {
    if(direction == "down") {
     $(".scroll").find('div').css('background', '#ffffff');
     $(".scroll").find('span').css('color', '#ffffff');
    } else {
      // Scrolling up, reverse the process
     $(".scroll").find('div').css('background', '#252A2F');
     $(".scroll").find('span').css('color', '#252A2F');
    }
  },
  offset: '100%'
});
```

Link to [a codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZyYLbg)

Comment: Of course it doesn't, because you only added this code to the light section.

Comment: I updated the codepen, now inverting the color on scrolling up, and also changing color on the dark sections.